# Can't get a pointer-to-structure array to work

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

I have the following code of a pointer-to-structure array, but I can't get the Insert function working

```
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std ;

    typedef struct data
    {
        int key ;
        char name[50] ; 
        int year ;
    } tdata ;

    typedef tdata* pdata ;

    pdata create ( int n )
    {
        pdata aux = ( pdata ) malloc ( n * sizeof (tdata ) ) ;
        return aux ;
    }

    pdata insert ( int n , tdata *array[] )
    {
        int i , k ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++ )
        {
            cin >> k ;
            (*array)[i].key = k;

        }
    }
```

It has been a while since I worked with pointer to structure arrays, so I don't think I quite remember how it is done. When I build this code using NetBeans/MinGW/MSYS it builds just fine, but I get the following error when I try to run it:

RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,511, total time: 69ms)

Any help is appreciated.

As some people asked, I've written a main(). Here it is:

```
    int main ( )
    {
        int n ;
        cin >> n ;
        pdata data =create(n);
        data = insert(n, &data);

        return 0;
    }
```

IMPORTANT EDIT:
   I'm getting the same exit failure number even for a program as simple as:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<n;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uhm. This looks like C, not C++. Are you sure you mean C++? (In that case, the headers are wrong, though.)

Comment: probably you run some main() function not this code. Can you please paste it?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `malloc` in C++: use `new` instead. Otherwise the object is not constructed properly.

Comment: @Bathsheba It’s not a good idea to use `new` in C++. Use automatic memory management instead.

Comment: I think this is not a good idea to write code. Better outsource.

Comment: @lizusek My main() is completely empty.

Comment: and doesn't return 0?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm pretty sure I'm running C++, because I do not get any compile errors on cin statement. Also file extension is .cpp

Comment: you definitely run C++. What about return 0?

Comment: @lizusek it only has a return 0; statement

Comment: @Pedro Maybe, but the code you wrote is how you’d write code in C, not C++. While that’s (barely) *valid* C++, it’s undeniably very bad, and overly complicated C++. You seem to be learning C++ from a very bad book or course.

Comment: I know I can implement this with Classes and facilitate my work, but the Course Professor wants it written with structures, specifically array of pointers to structures...

Comment: @KonradRudolph What are you talking about? C++ doesn't have automatic reference counting, and this poster looks like he is a long way from learning about `unique_ptr` and stuff like that.

Comment: It is literally impossible to tell what is wrong, because we need to see the `main` function. But I'll assume you are calling stuff in the predicted order.

As several other commenters have pointed out, stylistically this is poor verging on just plain wrong. It misuses C idioms in places C++ has much better solutions. Can you tell us a little bit about where this code is coming from? Class assignment? Book?

UPDATE: I see, class assignment.

Comment: It is running fine here: http://ideone.com/FsFgCs

Comment: @Andrew **First** you learn the high-level stuff, then the low-level one. And this code probably doesn’t need (and shouldn’t use) any smart pointers at all, value types are a clearly superior solution.

Comment: @Pedro Your instructor is, quite frankly, not very good then.

Comment: what did the debugger say

Comment: Also, name is just a `char`? Shouldn't it be `char*`?

Comment: Can't even run the debuger. The Code exits with the above mentioned exit code

Comment: comment out all the code and change main to cout << "hello"; return 0. And then build back up from there

Comment: @pm100 it runs flawlessly as expected when i do that

Comment: so now set a breakpoint in main - just to prove you can do it. THen add tings back in

Comment: @pm100: He isn't returning anything from insert. I figured it out here: http://ideone.com/FsFgCs

Comment: @KonradRudolph Truth is, he should probably just learn std::vector. Whoever he is paying for this class, he should demand a refund.

Comment: There is something wrong here if you still get a runtime error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code was the MinGW Tool Chain, that was installed wrong. I re-installed it and it worked. Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that

1. Your `char` should be a `char*` for a name
2. Change your `insert` function to `pdata insert ( int n , tdata *array )`
3. Change `(*array)[i].key` to `array[i].key`
4. You need to return the modified array from your function (e.g. `return array;`)
5. Add statement such as `tdata* pdata` instead of just `pdata data`.
6. Change your `insert` call in `main` to `insert(n, data);`
7. Free the memory allocated for array with malloc (call free).
8. Once you do that, you will stop getting runtime errors.

Running example here: http://ideone.com/FsFgCs

Comment: @Gl Joe array[i].key ?

Comment: @lizusek: You get no match for operator[]. So you'd either need to overload the [] operator for your struct, or you'd need to do what I showed

Comment: What are you talking about? array is an array

Comment: @lizusek: Arrays decay into pointers when passed to a function. You can't do (*array)[0].key. What does (*array) point to? Probably some other element, not the array itself. Therefore, you would then try to get index 0 (e.g [0]) of some field, which you can't do.

Comment: @Gl Joe array[0] is first tdata* .You are mixing things up

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. In your ideone example you have changed the function signature, so your array is not the same as the array in OP's function. So your answer is not correct.

Comment: I was referring to OP code, you were referring to your change. You should be more clear what you are referring to because default is OP's code. When I say "array[i] is a pointer" I mean this array[i] that is present in his code not somewhere on the internet, so make clear: array[i] in my changed code. Also there is nothing like my code here, please don't try to be rude. Last thing is your online example is example of memory leak, please use free() somewhere.

Comment: Have a good night Gl Joe, you were right about the pointer to array, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are omitting a return statement:

```
pdata insert ( int n , tdata *array[] )
    {
        int i , k ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++ )
        {
            cin >> k ;
            (*array)[i].key = k;

        }
    }
```

Omitting the return statement in a **non-void** function [Except main()] and using the returned value in your code invokes *Undefined Behaviour*.

> ISO C++-98[Section 6.6.3/2]
>
> A return statement with an expression can be used only in functions
>   returning a value; the value of the expression is returned to the
>   caller of the function. If required, the expression is implicitly
>   converted to the return type of the function in which it appears. A
>   return statement can involve the construction and copy of a temporary
>   object (class.temporary). Flowing off the end of a function is
>   equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined
>   behavior in a value-returning function.

This means anything can happen, including returning -1,073,741,511.

```
data = insert(n, &data);  // undefined behavior
```

---

But there are also other problems with your code. Possible solution was given by Gl Joe with my addition of 7th hint:

1. Your `char` should be a `char*` for a name
2. Change your `insert` function to `pdata insert ( int n , tdata *array )`
3. Change `(*array)[i].key` to `array[i].key`
4. You need to return the modified array from your function (e.g. `return array;`)
5. Add statement such as `tdata* pdata` instead of just `pdata data`.
6. Change your `insert` call in `main` to `insert(n, data);`
7. Free the memory allocated for array with malloc (call free).

Answer (score -1):

I think the bug is that you are working with an pointer to an array of structures, which is something of an array of arrays. You don't want this.

When you pass arrays around like this, you are basically passing a pointer to the beginning of the array. (You have to pass the size separately. In a class, you can encapsulate this, but your version is pretty much raw C.)

Change to

```
 pdata insert ( int n , tdata *array )
```

Notice the brackets have disappeared.